# Apps Script email trigger fails for other users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I wrote an apps script that will send an email on Google Forms submit (trigger container is the linked Google Sheet). The problem is that I want the email to be FROM the user that submits the form entry and it only works if that user adds their own Trigger to the Apps Script. And then when I have a trigger for each user, of course all the other triggers fail. So that's not a graceful solution either. Any ideas how I can do this gracefully?

I've tried to send a prompt for trigger authentication on loading of the google form, but that doesn't work either.
I tried deploying my script as a webapp, but got stuck on authentication...